# Why did a question become a Community Wiki?

Tags: support

Why did [What are common mistakes that you see in "professional" designs?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/what-are-common-mistakes-that-you-see-in-professional-designs) become a community wiki?

When I'd originally posted it, I was worried it may be too subjective.  After positive initial response I'd removed my "this may be subjective" caveat.  After reading about [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), I rethought my edit and rolled it back.  After the rollback, it was listed as a Community Wiki.

Is this something I did inadvertently?  I'm aware questions get CW status after several edits, but I was surprised to see it after 1 edit and 1 rollback.

It doesn't really matter, I'm just curious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

This question fits the guidelines for this perfectly. It has value, but is a list question with no real correct answer. As you stated originally, it was a subjective type question, but it had value, so that's what happened to it.

Comment: Makes total sense.  I missed that paragraph and thought maybe I had edited it wrong.  Thanks!